# How to loop through a bunch of sentences

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a div which contains a bunch of statements. I organized these statements in a `<ul>` list for now but this can change. How can I display these statements one at time in a rotating manner (each maybe every 4 seconds). I'm also looking at having a pause button to hold the current statement in place but I want to get the basic thing first.

```
<div id="statements">
  <ul>
     <li>Statement 1</li>
     <li>Statement 2</li>
     <li>Statement 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YSPe7/

```
var statements = $('#statements > ul > li').slice(1).hide().end();

var i = 0;
function rotate() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        statements.eq(i).fadeOut(800, function() {
            i = ++i % statements.length;
            statements.eq( i ).fadeIn(800, rotate);
        });
    }, 4000);
}
rotate();
```

Basically, we're hiding all except the first statement, then referencing the entire set.

Then we call a `rotate()` function. Inside the function there's a `setTimeout()` to cause a 4 second delay.

When the code in the timeout runs, it does a the [`fadeOut()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method on the statement at the current value of `i`.

The `fadeOut()` has a callback that increments `i` (or sets it back to 0) and does a the [`fadeIn()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method on that new element.

The `.fadeIn()` also has a callback, which is the same `rotate()` function, which starts the process all over.

---

If you don't want to pollute the namespace with `i`, pass it as an argument to `rotate()` like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YSPe7/1/

```
var statements = $('#statements > ul > li').slice(1).hide().end();

function rotate(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        statements.eq(i).fadeOut(800, function() {
            i = ++i % statements.length;
            statements.eq( i ).fadeIn(800, function() {
                rotate(i);
            });
        });
    }, 4000);
}
rotate(0);
```

---

**EDIT:** The code can be reduced a bit by using the [`delay()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method instead of `setTimeout`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YSPe7/2/

```
var statements = $('#statements > ul > li').slice(1).hide().end();

function rotate(i) {
    statements.eq(i).delay(4000).fadeOut(800, function() {
        i = ++i % statements.length;
        statements.eq( i ).fadeIn(800, function() {
            rotate(i);
        });
    });
}
rotate(0);
```

Comment: @patrick dw +1 Thanks a lot. Not to sound completely dense, but what if my markup looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/SmJMP/ where I have 2 divs in each statement div.

Comment: @zmol: It will be much simpler if you can wrap the pairs in a div. Is that a possibility?

Comment: @zmol: [Here's how it could work](http://jsfiddle.net/SmJMP/1/) if they're in pairs. There's a bit more complexity because we need to prevent the callback functions from running twice, therefore doubling the number of `fadeIn()` and `rotate()` calls each time. If you can wrap the pairs, then it is just a matter of changing the selector.

Comment: @patrick dw I can wrap each statement in a div, it makes more sense. Do you mind taking a final look at this http://jsfiddle.net/XsWEe/

Comment: @zmol: Yes, it is just the same as my solutions above, just change the selector. http://jsfiddle.net/XsWEe/1/ (also, you needed to select the jQuery library on the left in jsFiddle).

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin that you can use that will do exactly what you want.  It is called jShowOff (http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/).  There are plently of examples there that should get your started.